# Как устранить бесконечный цикл при React.useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook

Parent.tsx

```
const Parent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
        const [truncated, setTruncated] = useState<boolean>(); 
    
        return (
           <Child setTruncated={setTruncated} />
        )
    }
```

Child.tsx

```
const Child: React.FunctionComponent = ({ setTruncated }) => {
    const truncated = .....

    useEffect(() => {
       setRef(truncated);
    }, [truncated, setTruncated]);

    return (
       <></>
    )
}
```

Comment: все зависит от того, что такое `const truncated = .....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как быстрое решение — решение, описанное ниже.

```
let lockEffectHandler = false;
useEffect(() => {
  if (lockEffectHandler) {
    lockEffectHandler = false;
  } else {
    lockEffectHandler = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      lockEffectHandler = false;
    });
    setRef(truncated);
  }
}, [truncated, setTruncated]);
```

Однако лучше просто не вызывать изменение значения в обработчике изменений этого же значения.

UPD. Это ужасное решение. На сколько возможно — НЕ используйте его.
Лучшим решением будет определить, как вызывать необходимую логику обходя рекурсию.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое